# extraReducers not working when I'm trying to watch for the action on my slice on the same file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I'm trying to trigger the extra reducers, everytime when i dispatch the fillForm action. but the code isn't working. Any help ?

```
export const userSelectSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userSelect",
  initialState: {
    name: localStoreData?.name || "",
    salary: localStoreData?.salary || "",
    job: localStoreData?.job || "",
    location: localStoreData?.location || "",
    eligibility: localStoreData?.eligibility || "",
  },
  reducers: {
    fillForm: (state, action) => {
      state.name = action.payload.name;
      state.salary = action.payload.salary;
      state.job = action.payload.job;
      state.location = action.payload.location;

      localStorage.setItem(
        "userSelect",
        JSON.stringify({
          name: action.payload.name,
          salary: action.payload.salary,
          job: action.payload.job,
          location: action.payload.location,
        })
      );
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(createAction('fillForm'), (state, action) => {
      // extra reducer code goes here
      console.log('sdcjknsdcjnsdjhcbsdjhb')
      state.eligibility = 'sdckjsdcjnsdjcbdshjcb'
    });
  },
});
```

I tried several methods but wheren't of any help

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentatin](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice#extrareducers):

> reducers specified with extraReducers are meant to reference "external" actions

> If two fields from reducers and extraReducers happen to end up with the same action type string, the function from reducers will be used to handle that action type.

This is the case in example you have provided. You can not have the same action handled twice in the same slice. `ExtraReducers` is meant to allow you respond to other action types besides the types the slice has generated. So you can either

1. add `state.eligibility = 'sdckjsdcjnsdjcbdshjcb'` to existing reducer

```
export const userSelectSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userSelect",
  initialState: {
  //...
  },
  reducers: {
    fillForm: (state, action) => {
      // ... do your stuff
      console.log('fillForm slice reducer')
      state.eligibility = 'sdckjsdcjnsdjcbdshjcb' // add code from extra reducers
    },
  },
});
```

2. Use the extra reducer in diffreent slice

```js
export const someOtherSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'otherSlice',
  initialState: {
    //...
  },
  reducers: {
    // No fillForm action here
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(createAction('fillForm'), (state, action) => {
      // extra reducer code goes here
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('fillForm extraReducers')
    })
  }
})
```

3. Have diffrent action in extraReducers, to avoid name conflict

```js
export const fillFormExtra = createAction('fillForm')
export const userSelectSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userSelect',
  initialState: {
    eligibility: ''
  },
  reducers: {
    fillForm: (state, action) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('fillForm slice reducer')
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(createAction('fillForm'), (state, action) => {
      // extra reducer code goes here
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('fillForm extraReducers')
      state.eligibility = 'sdckjsdcjnsdjcbdshjcb'
    })
  }
})
```

and dispatch them separately

```js
dispatch(userSelectSlice.actions.fillForm({}))
dispatch(fillFormExtra())
```